# Edge/Chrome Dev Tools delay in loading source map

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, svelte

As I debug in DevTools of either Chrome or Edge, sometimes the debugger loads my source map (generated by rollup) pretty immediately, sometimes I have to wait 10 seconds or so, and sometimes it never requests the source map. I'm watching the web log and can see when it requests the map file (bundle.js.map). The browser simply doesn't ask for it sometimes or takes forever before deciding to ask for it.

Any ideas? I can't step through code until the source map loads, so this just makes me sit and wait and get nothing done.

Comment: can you add a spinner to your page as visual indicator that the page is still loading data?

Comment: The issue is source map loading in the debugger, not page content loading for the user.